# slf4j disable debug spamming messages

Tags: java, debugging, slf4j, spam-prevention

Well, I don't remember having changed anything, but I started get spammed with a lot of debug messages from varius depencencies (JDA, Mongo driver, etc). How can I disable it? Thanks in advance

[Spam picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tHzu1.png)

Comment: You'll need to specify a lot more details about your logging setup. SLF4J is just a facade over actual logging infrastructure.

Comment: My code don't use slf4j, but the libraries included does.

Comment: Well, *something* in your dependencies is providing a binding for SLF4J to display log messages. Whatever logging system it's using, that's that you need to configure.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your application's interactions with MongoDB is getting logged into console. You may have turned on the DEBUG on your MongoDB. Hence all interactions with the MongodDB is getting logged.

You need to set a couple of system properties before loading any of the MongoDB Java driver classes:

```
// Disable MongoDB logging in general
System.setProperty("DEBUG.MONGO", "false");

// Disable DB operation tracing
System.setProperty("DB.TRACE", "false");
```

Comment: Ok, but what about the other dependencies? That flood occours on everything that uses slf4j, not just mongo